# Equivalent passwords ACPC 2014

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge

I am preparing for ACM-TCPC (Tunisia). So I started solving problems from past ACM-ACPC versions. But I got stuck in the [Problem I from 2014](http://acmacpc.org/files/acpc/acpc2014.pdf).

The problem consists of finding the number of **non-equivalent** passwords in list of passwords. Two passwords, A and B, are equivalent if `len(A) == len(B)`  and `|A[i] -B[i]|` is the same for i in `[0..len(A)]` (`len` is the length of the password and `|x|` is the absolute value of `x`).

#### Examples:

Input:

```
000
111
222
```

Output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
1111
123
214
2222
```

Output:

```
2
```

Input

```
43434
54545
45454
```

Output:

```
2
```

My code works fine and it solves the [Judges I/O](http://acmacpc.org/files/archive/2014/acm-acpc-2014-io-I.zip), However it takes a plentiful amount of time!

The code I wrote:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class Password {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] str_tab ;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = null;
        List<String> l = null;
        try {
            int[] tab = null;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("./password.in")));
            PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter("./passwrd.out");
            int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
                l = new ArrayList<String>();
                int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    l.add(br.readLine().toString());
                }
                wr.println("Case "+(i+1)+": " +solve(l));
            }
            wr.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    public static int solve(List<String> l){
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        ls.add(l.get(0));
        int j= 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < l.size(); i++) {
            j = 0;
            while(j<ls.size() && !isEq(l.get(i),ls.get(j))) j++;
            if(j == ls.size()) ls.add(l.get(i));
        }

        return ls.size();
    }
    public static boolean isEq(String p1, String p2){
        if(p1.length() != p2.length()) return false;
        int diff = Math.abs(p1.charAt(0) - p2.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 1; i <p1.length(); i++) {

            if(Math.abs(p1.charAt(i) - p2.charAt(i)) != diff){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Did I get it wrong? Is there advice that could help me improve my code? (performance, organization or anything)

Comment: From really quickly looking at your code, normally `system.out` calls are costly and `e.printstacktrace` does nothing and exception are costly if it throws many times. I would make sure the text output is buffered or commenting the sysout calls to see if this is the one of the big drawbacks.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Sorry I Changed it just to see how fast the calculation happens. I was  writing it to a file using`wr.println`. The problem seems to be from my algorithm since it take a long time to print out the result ( more than 30 seconds for 100000 passwords).

Comment: All the operations `Integer.parseInt(p1.charAt(i)+"")` are fishy. You take a char (which is a number), convert it to String just to convert it to Integer? Why don't you substract them directly?

Comment: @MirMasej Thanks I change it to `Math.abs(p1.charAt(i) - p2.charAt(i)) != diff`, However no great difference in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lint

`str_tab`, `hm`, and `tab` are all unused variables.

In `br.readLine().toString()`, the `.toString()` is superfluous, as `br.readLine()` already returns a string.

In `main()`, the `for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)` loop would be better as `for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++)` so that you can avoid the `(i+1)`.

Instead of `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`, you could just declare `main(String[] args) throws Exception`.  But what kind of exception?  The code would be clearer if you narrowed it down to `throws IOException`.  (It's also possible to get a `NumberFormatException`, but for a contest problem, I wouldn't bother handling it.)

### Skeleton

I would use the following outline:

```
public class Password {

    public static class DistinctPasswordCounter {
        public DistinctPasswordCounter(Scanner in) {
            this.in = in;
            this.n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            …
        }

        public int count() {
            while (this.n --> 0) {
                …
            }
            return …;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException, NoSuchElementException {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("password.in"));
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("password.out")) {
            int t = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
                DistinctPasswordCounter counter = new DistinctPasswordCounter(in);
                out.printf("Case %d: %d\n", i, counter.count());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notable improvements:

- `password.out` would be a more logical filename for the output.
- Use try-with-resources for `AutoCloseable` resources.
- Using `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` would let you not have to deal with `IOException`.
- Passing a `Scanner` instead of a `List<String>` lets each test case work on the fly as the input streams in.
- `solve()` doesn't really "solve".  I'd pick a more descriptive name.  Here, I've instantiated an object to represent each test case.  (I think that a good solution requires more state than I would like to pack into a single function.)  If the challenge had not required the program to be named `Password`, I would have just used `DistinctPasswordCounter` as the name of the class, and eliminated the inner class.

### Strategy

**Your `solve()` compares each password with every previously seen password, which makes it O(*N*<sup>2</sup>).**  It's not surprising that the solution is slow, considering that *N* is large (up to 10<sup>5</sup>).

Consider a different strategy: when you encounter a password, also note all possible variants of it.  For example, if the password `31415` appears, then also register the variants `20304`, `20306`, `20324`, `20326`, etc.

How many variants would we be talking about?  Given an original password, such as `31415`, there would be…

- `31415` itself
- the ±1 variants:
  $${2 \choose 4}{0 \choose 2}{3 \choose 5}{0 \choose 2}{4 \choose 6}$$
  … of which there are 2<sup>5</sup>: `20304`, `20306`, `20324`, `20326`, `20504`, `20506`, `20524`, `20526`, `22304`, `22306`, `22324`, `22326`, `22504`, `22506`, `22524`, `22526`, `40304`, `40306`, `40324`, `40326`, `40504`, `40506`, `40524`, `40526`, `42304`, `42306`, `42324`, `42326`, `42504`, `42506`, `42524`, `42526`.
- the ±2 variants:
  $${1 \choose 5}\left(3\right){2 \choose 6}\left(3\right){3 \choose 7}$$
  … of which there are 2<sup>3</sup>: `13233`, `13237`, `13633`, `13637`,  `53233`, `53237`, `53633`, `53637`.
- the ±3 variants:
  $${0 \choose 6}\left(4\right){1 \choose 7}\left(4\right){2 \choose 8}$$
  … of which there are 2<sup>3</sup>: `04142`, `04148`, `04742`, `04748`, `64142`, `64148`, `64742`, `64748`.
- the ±4 variants:
  $$\left(7\right)\left(5\right){0 \choose 8}\left(5\right){1 \choose 9}$$
  … of which there are 2<sup>2</sup>: `75051`, `75059`, `75851`, `75859`.
- the ±5 variants:
  $$\left(8\right)\left(6\right)\left(9\right)\left(6\right)\left(0\right)$$
  … of which there is 1: `86960`.

In the worst case, a password like `44444` or `55555` would generate 1+32+32+32+32+1 = 130 entries.  If you stick them all in a `HashSet` with O(1) insertion and lookup time, then the solution would be O(130 *N*), which is much better than O(*N*<sup>2</sup>) for *N* ≫ 130.

In practice, there will probably be much fewer than 130 variants.  For example, `31415` has just 54 variants.  Passwords that are shorter or that have a wide distribution of digits would have fewer variants.  Passwords that are equivalent to another password would generate no variants at all.  (For large *N*, the proportion of passwords that are equivalent to an existing password should rise dramatically due to the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).)

### Suggested solution

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Password {

    public static class DistinctPasswordCounter {
        private final Scanner in;
        private final HashSet<String> seenPasswords;
        private int n, distinctCount;

        public DistinctPasswordCounter(Scanner in) {
            this.in = in;
            this.n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

            // 100 is a rough estimate of the number of variants
            // per password, based on (5 * Math.pow(2, maxLength)).
            // For very large n, it could probably be tuned lower
            // due to the Birthday Paradox.
            this.seenPasswords = new HashSet<>(100 * this.n);
        }

        public int count() {
            while (this.n --> 0) {
                String password = this.in.nextLine();
                if (this.seenPasswords.add(password)) {
                    // No variant of this password has been seen before
                    this.distinctCount++;
                    int variants = this.addVariants(password);
                    // System.err.printf("%3d variants of %s\n", variants + 1, password);
                }
            }
            return this.distinctCount;
        }

        private int addVariants(String password) {
            int diff = 0, variants = 0, v;
            while (0 < (v = this.addVariants(password, ++diff, 0))) {
                variants += v;
            }
            return variants;
        }

        private int addVariants(String password, int diff, int pos) {
            if (pos >= password.length()) {
                this.seenPasswords.add(password);
                return 1;
            }
            char c1 = (char)(password.charAt(pos) - diff),
                 c2 = (char)(password.charAt(pos) + diff);
            String head = password.substring(0, pos),
                   tail = password.substring(pos + 1);
            return (c1 < '0' ? 0 : this.addVariants(head + c1 + tail, diff, pos + 1)) +
                   (c2 > '9' ? 0 : this.addVariants(head + c2 + tail, diff, pos + 1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException, NoSuchElementException {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("password.in"));
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("password.out")) {
            int t = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
                DistinctPasswordCounter counter = new DistinctPasswordCounter(in);
                out.printf("Case %d: %d\n", i, counter.count());
            }
        }
    }
}
```